# how to read environment variable in chef recipe

Tags: environment-variables, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am writing deployment script, it needs to perform based on the system variable. Is there any way to read specific environmental variable through chef recipe ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ruby native way to manage environmental variables ([ruby-doc link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ENV.html)).
Thus you can reference a environmental variable from your recipe directly using ENV['MY_VARIABLE'].